# how to get latest record in the two dataframes using spark scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

df1

```
userName | address | phone | Date
user1 | address1 | 797798 | 2020-09-15
user2 | address2 | 464665 | 2020-09-15
user3 | address3 | 123333 | 2020-09-15
```

Df2

```
userName | address | phone | Date
user2 | addresNew2 | 333333 | 2020-09-20
user1 | address1 | 44444 | 2020-09-20
user5 | address5 | 4442221 | 2020-09-20
```

OUTPUT::

```
user2 | addresNew2 | 333333 | 2020-09-20
user1 | address1 | 44444 | 2020-09-20
user5 | address5 | 4442221 | 2020-09-20
user3 | address3 | 123333 | 2020-09-15
```

Comment: Perform union of df1 and df1. Then on the result dataframe use window function(rank() or dense_rank()) partition by userName and order by Date descending. The result will have the rank 1 for the latest userName filter all the rank == 1 records.

Comment: Thanks for your response. but i am getting output like this.+--------+----------+-------+----------+
|userName|address   |phone  |Date      |
+--------+----------+-------+----------+
|user1   |address1  |44444  |2020-09-20|
|user5   |address5  |4442221|2020-09-20|
|user3   |address3  |123333 |2020-09-15|
|user2   |addresNew2|333333 |2020-09-20|
+--------+----------+-------+----------+

Comment: this is  my code :                                                                                                           
  val total=df1.union(df2)
    import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions._
    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
    var windowspec=Window.partitionBy(  "userName").orderBy(col("Date"). desc)
    var total2=total.withColumn("rank", dense_rank().over(windowspec)).filter("rank==1").drop("rank")
    total2.show(false)

Comment: The code looks good to me and I think it will work. Also, use val instead of var whenever possible.